# Finding the extremal curve satisfying a variable endpoint

Tags: analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations

Below is a question I am trying to solve, and my attempt.

$\int_0^T \frac{\dot{x}^2}{t^3} \mathrm{d} t$, where $x(0)=1 $ and $x(T)$ lies on the curve 
Transversal condition:

$$f-(\dot{c} -\dot{x})\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}}=0$$
$$\frac{\dot{x}^2}{t^3}-(2t-2-\dot{x})(\frac{2\dot{x}}{t^3})=0$$
$$\frac{\dot{x}^2}{t^3}-\left(\frac{4t\dot{x}-4\dot{x}-2\dot{x}^2}{t^3}\right)=0$$
$$3\dot{x}^2-4t\dot{x}+4\dot{x}=0$$
$$3\dot{x}-4t + 4=0$$
$$\dot{x}=\frac{4t-4}{3}$$
$$x=\frac{2t^2-4t}{3}+C$$
$$1=C$$
$$x=\frac{2t^2-4t}{3}+1$$

The apparent answer is $x(t) = \frac{t^4}{8}+1$, where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first use $E-L$ and then sub in for $\dot{x}$ when you start using transversality conditions. You will see immediately that you will have some $T^4$ and that is where that comes from in the actual answer.

If you need further clarification ask and I will edit.